# Log Parser New Visits

Tags: logging, logparser

I'm trying to use log parser to only show the source that an ip address used during its first visit to the site.  I want to include all sources and the number of ip addresses that accessed the site from this source on its first visit.  Does anyone have a suggestion on what coding I would use?

Answer (score 1):

With "sources" you mean the *cs-referer* [sic] HTTP header, which is the header containing the URL of the page that directed the user to the current page, correct?

If so, then you should use something like:
"`SELECT cs-referer, COUNT(DISTINCT s-ip) FROM <your log> GROUP BY cs-referer`"

This will count ALL source pages, including the ones from your site on subsequent visits. You can add a WHERE to filter out values of cs-referer from your domain, you can check examples at http://logparserplus.com/Examples.